# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

I am trying to add `floating search view` [library](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) to my android app. After adding the dependencies I got:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1.
Required by:
project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

So, I have added following dependencies to my module `Gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
```

After sync `Gradle` file, I got the same error. Then I clean the project and even https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview the `Invalidate cache` to the project but the same response.

My `Android Studio` is updated and API level 25 is installed.

What am I doing wrong here?

## Gradle file

(Editing Gradle file after a suggestion)

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.seeker"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: `Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.` or maybe you need to update it.

Comment: @Yupi It's already installed and updted (Mentioned in the question) :)

Comment: Can you screenshot the sdk manager's SDK Tools tab with 'show package details' checked from within Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` your `compileSdkVersion` must be **25**, so update it.

In the same way, consider to upgrade your `buildToolsVersion` to version **25.0.3**